# passing array of objects from js to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, get

I am trying to pass an array of objects from js to rails

```
data.test = [{test: 'asdas'}]

$.ajax({
  url: 'evaluate.json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
  },
  dataType : "json"
});
```

Rails

```
def evaluate
   logger.info("#{params.test}")
end
```

Here the logger statement always gives me out put as

```
{"0"=>{"test"=>"asdas"}}
```

I am expecting the below log in rails.

```
 [{:test=>"asdas"}]
```

Comment: did you solved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `JSON.stringify` in Javascript, which takes either an array or hash as its argument (since these are the only valid JSON constructions). It returns a form which is the Javascript object serialized to JSON.

On the Ruby side, you'll receive a JSON encoded string, so you'll need to `require 'json'` (this is done automatically in Rails) and use `JSON.parse(string)`. This will give you a Ruby object.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
data.test = [{test: 'asdas'}]

$.ajax({
  url: 'evaluate.json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),  // Explicit JSON serialization
  contentType: 'application/json',  // Overwrite the default content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  success: function(data){
  },
  dataType : "json"
});
```

Comment: yes yes yes! This is what I've been looking for for ages. Thanks. What you said and others didn't was that you need BOTH 'dataType' and 'contentType' for it to work (or I did anyway) as well as the stringified JSON. I had to add my authenticity token as well.

Comment: This answer is somewhat obsolete. You should use promise instead of the `success` callback.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer.